# Handling Callbacks

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a method in an objective-C class. It has 2 callback functions written in C. The class pointer i.e. `self` is passed to these functions as `void *`. In the C functions I create a pointer of type class and assign the `void *` parameter.
The first callback function executes successfully. But the `void *` pointer becomes `nil` in the 2nd callback function. Note that I haven't tweaked pointer in the first callback but still I get `nil` in 2nd callback.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

For example:

```
kr = IOServiceAddMatchingNotification(gNotifyPort, kIOFirstMatchNotification,
                                      matchingDict, RawDeviceAdded, NULL,
                                      &gRawAddedIter);

RawDeviceAdded(NULL, gRawAddedIter, self);
```

This works fine. But below function receives `self` as `nil`.

```
kr = IOServiceAddMatchingNotification(gNotifyPort, kIOFirstMatchNotification,
                                      matchingDict, BulkTestDeviceAdded, NULL,
                                      &gBulkTestAddedIter);

BulkTestDeviceAdded(NULL, gBulkTestAddedIter, self);
```

Comment: It'll be easier to help if you can edit to add code that shows what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 11):

Are your problems specifically with the IOKit callback routines?  The problem with the specific example you gave is that the IOServiceMatchingCallback takes only 2 parameters, not 3.  You need your RawDeviceAdded() and BulkTestDeviceAdded() callback functions to match the IOServiceMatchingCallback prototype and to accept self as the first parameter (refCon), not the 3rd. Also, you need to pass in self as the second-to-last parameter of IOServiceAddMatchingNotification() to get it passed back to you by the callback.

A common method for handling C callbacks in Objective-C code is just to have a static function that forwards the callback to your instance.  So, your example callback code would look like this:

```
static RawDeviceAdded(void* refcon, io_iterator_t iterator)
{
    [(MyClass*)refcon rawDeviceAdded:iterator];
}

@implementation MyClass
- (void)setupCallbacks
{
    // ... all preceding setup snipped
    kr = IOServiceAddMatchingNotification(gNotifyPort,kIOFirstMatchNotification, matchingDict,RawDeviceAdded,(void*)self,&gRawAddedIter );
    // call the callback method once to 'arm' the iterator
    [self rawDeviceAdded:gRawAddedIterator];
}
- (void)rawDeviceAdded:(io_iterator_t)iterator
{
    // take care of the iterator here, making sure to complete iteration to re-arm it
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, callbacks in Objective-C are handled by passing a delegate object and a selector to perform on that delegate.  For example, this method will call a method on its delegate after logging a message, passing both itself and the message that was logged.

```
- (void)logMessage:(NSString *)message
          delegate:(id)delegate
    didLogSelector:(SEL)didLogSelector
{
    NSLog(@"%@", message);

    if (delegate && didLogSelector && [delegate respondsToSelector:didLogSelector]) {
        (void) [delegate performSelector:didLogSelector
                              withObject:self
                              withObject:message];
    }
}
```

You might call it in code like this:

```
- (void)sayHello
{
    [logger logMessage:@"Hello, world"
              delegate:self
        didLogSelector:@selector(messageLogger:didLogMessage:)];
}

- (void)messageLogger:(id)logger
        didLogMessage:(NSString *)message
{
    NSLog(@"Message logger %@ logged message '%@'", logger, message);
}
```

You can also use `objc_msgSend()` directly instead, though you need to understand the Objective-C runtime enough to choose which variant to use and how to construct the prototype and function pointer through which to call it.  (It's the mechanism by which message sends are actually implemented in Objective-C — what the compiler normally generates calls to in order to represent `[]` expressions.)

Comment: Sorry - before code was posted, I thought the question was about how to write code that implements a callback system in Objective-C, not about using C callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what Objective-C's selector is for:
[http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSInvocationOperation_Class](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSInvocationOperation_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

The API isn't very intuitive, but its fine once you understand it

You might need to do some refactoring as well, now there might be a better way, but when I had this problem my solution was to refactor and use InvoationOperation.