# C Callback in Objective-C (IOKIT)

Tags: objective-c, c, callback, hid, iokit

I am trying to write some code that interacts with an USB device in Objective C, and I got stuck on setting the callback function for incoming reports. In my case it's an IOKIT function but I think the problem is more general as I (apparently) don't know how to correctly set a C callback function in Objective-C. I've got a Class "USBController" that handles the io functions

USBController.m:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>
#include <IOKit/hid/IOHIDLib.h>
#import "USBController.h"

static void Handle_IOHIDDeviceIOHIDReportCallback(
                                              void *          inContext,          // context from IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputReportCallback
                                              IOReturn        inResult,           // completion result for the input report operation
                                              void *          inSender,           // IOHIDDeviceRef of the device this report is from
                                              IOHIDReportType inType,             // the report type
                                              uint32_t        inReportID,         // the report ID
                                              uint8_t *       inReport,           // pointer to the report data
                                              CFIndex         InReportLength)     // the actual size of the input report
{
    printf("hello"); //just to see if the function is called
}

@implementation USBController
- (void)ConnectToDevice {
    ...
    IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputReportCallback(tIOHIDDeviceRefs[0], report, reportSize,
          Handle_IOHIDDeviceIOHIDReportCallback,(void*)self);
    ...
}
...
@end
```

All the functions are also declared in the header file.

I think I did pretty much the same as what I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316879/handling-callbacks-in-objective-c/), but it doesn't work. The project compiles nicely and everything works up till the moment there is input and the callback function is to be called. Then I get an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error. The first three arguments of the function are correct. I'm not so sure about the context..
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure at all that your EXEC_BAD_ACCESS depends on your callback. Indeed, if you say that it is called (I suppose you see the log) and since it only logs a message, there should be no problem with this.

EXEC_BAD_ACCESS is caused by an attempt to access an already deallocated object. You can get more information in two ways:

1. execute the program in debug mode, so when it crashes you will be able to see the stack content;
2. activate NSZombies or run the program using the performance tool Zombies; this will tell you exactly which object was accessed after its deallocation.

Comment: Well, it isn't called. There's no log message. How should I debug this? Zombies gives me no clue, there is no zombie object detected. What should I look for in the stack content? This is shown:
#0 0x7fffffe007c5 in __memcpy
I guess it's trying to copy something into an object that doesn't exist? But how can I figure out where it went wrong?

Comment: If you can see the stack trace, then you not can see the last functions called. From what you say, the only thing I can think of is that `report` is not preallocated, but you say that it is, so it should not be this... anyway, how the program gets to call `__memcpy` (stack trace) this *could* give you an hint

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't able to figure it out. I posted the full code here [link](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1202777), that might clarify things.. Thanks for your effort anyway.

Comment: would you try and schedule the device *after* setting the callback, say just before `IOHIDDeviceSetReport`? what about trying to remove the callback and see what happens? increase `report` size? I have really no other idea...

Answer (score 0):

I know how to fix this. When calling this:

```
IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputReportCallback(tIOHIDDeviceRefs[0], report, reportSize,
          Handle_IOHIDDeviceIOHIDReportCallback,(void*)self);
```

You don't include the code for the creation/type of the value called report. However the method name "Handle_IOHIDDeviceIOHIDReportCallback" comes from an Apple document where there is an error in the creation of the report value. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2187/_index.html

```
CFIndex reportSize = 64; 
uint8_t report = malloc( reportSize );  // <---- WRONG 
IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputReportCallback( deviceRef, 
                                        report,  
                                        reportSize,
                                        Handle_IOHIDDeviceIOHIDReportCallback,   
                                        context );
```

Instead do this:

```
uint8_t *report = (uint8_t *)malloc(reportSize);
```